# Adding .NET 4 to Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

How do I add additional .net framework to the Target framework drop down list in Visual Studio?  I would like to add .NET Framework 4.  Do I download the runtime from this website?

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral

[image]

Comment: Ever since .NET Core came out with the new minimal MSBuild project style the Project Properties page in VS is kinda useless: you will need to edit the `.csproj` file by hand.

Comment: Pick the right project template to get started.  If you want to target 4 then you need "Class Library (.NET Framework)".

Comment: @HansPassant can you provide link to download that?

Comment: Hmm, nobody needs to download that.  Use File > New > Project.  The choice you make now is important.

Comment: ok figured it out I selected wrong project when creating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option to install .NET 4 is available during VS installation.  To get .NET 4 selection pick the correct project type when creating new project.